# SSIS Automate Excel File Generation From Database

Tags: excel, ssis

I have been facing issues while package execution.

**What I have Done :**

I have created a Template which has only header in it and I have a table "Product". I tried to insert the data into excel sheet from "Product" table by using the excel template.
I have used 3 variable.

**Flow :**  File System Task => Data Flow Task => OLE DB Source => Excel Destination.

**Error :**

[Excel Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.

[Excel Destination [2]] Error: Opening a rowset for "result$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Thanks

Comment: VS_ISBROKEN usually means the columns changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KeithL 
Column name are same in template and SQL Table.

Comment: well do you a tab in Excel labeled result (proper case)? BTW, if you aren't formatting excel it would be a lot easier to write output to a csv which can be opened with excel.

Comment: @KeithL I have tried with tab name "Sheet1" and now rename the tab name "result" ( just for experiment). 
Actually I have following the tutorial, so I want do this with his way. otherwise I have inserted the data into excel sheet scuccefully without the template. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7bybXMcTqE&list=PLfVlcqqDh2Tjq2_9KeStQ6DUL3RxGNjpv&index=21&ab_channel=SatyarthProgrammingHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is miracle. I just solved this error...

You don't need to create a template (dummy) excel, you need only 3 components.

**1. Create `Execute SQL Task` according to [this](https://www.claytabase.co.uk/Database-Consultancy-Services/Technical-Articles/SQL-Server-Data/Create-a-Dynamic-Excel-File-with-Dynamic-Sheet-Names-SSIS) tutorial.**

When set everything except `SQLStatement` I suggest creating **empty** excel and connect to OLE DB source (your server table). When you add `excel destination` and connect with `excel destination manager`, you will see question that VS ask if you want to create table like this query (but with different data types):

```
CREATE TABLE `Result` (
    `ColName1` NVARCHAR(255),
    `ColName2` NVARCHAR(255),
    `ColName3` NVARCHAR(255),
    `ColName4` NVARCHAR(255)
)
```

*I don't know if I explained well, but you have previous step in tutorial.*

**2. Execute this task**

**3. Add `Data Flow Task` with `OLE DB Source` and `Excel Destination`**

With OLE DB select all that you need from your `Product` table

Connect `Excel Destination` with SAME `Excel Connection Manager` like in `Execute SQL Task`. From drop-down select `Result` sheet name.

> When you finish this delete this empty excel

**4. Create a variable that will contain path and excel file name**

**5. According to tutorial from first step, click on `Excel Connection Manager` -> Properties -> Expressions -> ... (on right) -> ExcelFilePath (from drop-down). In 2nd column write @[User::YourVariableName]**

### Crucial step

**6. In control flow, click on `Data Flow Task` and in properties for `DelayValidation` set `True`.**

If you have a question, write me in comment below.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @Marko .
I will try this solution.
Actually I have been following a tutorial. He is doing this with another way.
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7bybXMcTqE&list=PLfVlcqqDh2Tjq2_9KeStQ6DUL3RxGNjpv&index=21&ab_channel=SatyarthProgrammingHub]

Comment: @Learner Then at least reward my efforts.